# Fill columns in pandas dataframe that have N amount of empty values completely with zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take a line like:

```
df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

Instead of dropping the column based on the # of empty values, I want to fill that entire column with zeroes.

Thus, columns that only have one empty value will be untouched, while columns with 2+ empty values will be totally replaced with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the columns, and if the number of NA values is greater than 2, replace the columns with zeroes else keep the column as is:

```
for col in df.columns:
     df[col] = 0 if df[col].isna().sum() > 2 else df[col]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4,5,7],"col2":[1,2,3,4,np.NaN,2],"col3":[1,2,3,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
    temp=(((df!=df).sum())>=2)#nothing much is happening here its simply just a filter for nan elements
    temp1=df.columns
    for x in range(len(temp)):
      if temp[x]:
          df[temp1[x]]=0
    df
```

output:

```
     col1   col2    col3
    0   1   1.0     0
    1   2   2.0     0
    2   3   3.0     0
    3   4   4.0     0
    4   5   NaN     0
    5   7   2.0     0
```